# MS Project get name current project

Tags: c#, ms-office, office365, ms-project

For my project, i need to get the name of my current active document file of my ms project. But i can't find the function for get the file name...

someone know how te get the file name ?

I Use this :

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my VSTO add-in named `thisAddIn`, I accessed the project file information with this little example function (activated by a ribbon button)

```
    private void showFileAndPath_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {

        var name = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveProject.Name;
        var path = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveProject.Path;
        var fullName = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveProject.FullName;

        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(
            "name: " + name + Environment.NewLine + 
            "path: " + path + Environment.NewLine + 
            "fullName: " + fullName);
    }
```